# How to split with regex in javascript?

Tags: javascript

If I have the string

`PercentageValue = 99.9,\r\nCaseID = 9745683 PercentageValue = 90.3,\r\nCaseID = 9387593 PercentageValue = 88.6,\r\nCaseID = 4893448`

How can I parse it into:

```
[
    {PercentageValue : '99.9', CaseID : '9745683'},
    {PercentageValue : '90.3', CaseID : '9387593'},
    {PercentageValue : '88.6', CaseID : '4893448'}
]
```

There seems to be a space delimiter, but the issue is there are other spaces too.

Thanks

Comment: The JSON format you want to achieve is not correct. Maybe you would like `:` instead of `=` ?

Comment: thanks, fixed typo.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var str = 'PercentageValue = 99.9,\r\nCaseID = 9745683 PercentageValue = 90.3,\r\nCaseID = 9387593 PercentageValue = 88.6,\r\nCaseID = 4893448';
var array = str.replace(/\r\n/g, '').replace(/\s=\s/g, ':').split(' ');
var objs = array.map((el) => {
  return {
   [el.split(',')[0].split(':')[0]]: el.split(',')[0].split(':')[1],
   [el.split(',')[1].split(':')[0]]: el.split(',')[1].split(':')[1]  
  }
});
console.log(objs);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var str = "PercentageValue = 99.9,\r\nCaseID = 9745683 PercentageValue = 90.3,\r\nCaseID = 9387593 PercentageValue = 88.6,\r\nCaseID = 4893448";
var parse = "["+str.replace(/(\w+)\s=\s(\d+(\.\d)?),\r\n(\w+)\s=\s(\d+)/g, "{\"$1\":\"$2\",\"$4\":$5}").replace(/\}\s\{/g, "},{")+"]";
console.log(JSON.parse(parse));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var input = "PercentageValue = 99.9,\r\nCaseID = 9745683 PercentageValue = 90.3,\r\nCaseID = 9387593 PercentageValue = 88.6,\r\nCaseID = 4893448";
var res, resArray = [], re = /PercentageValue = (.*),\r\nCaseID = (\d*) ?/g; 
while (res = re.exec(input)) 
   resArray.push({PercentageValue: res[1], CaseID: res[2]})
```

Answer (score 0):

As shown by other answers, there are several ways to solve this. Here is an approach with `.reduce()`:

```js
var str = 'PercentageValue = 99.9,\r\nCaseID = 9745683 ' +     
          'PercentageValue = 90.3,\r\nCaseID = 9387593 ' +
          'PercentageValue = 88.6,\r\nCaseID = 4893448';

console.log(
  str
    .split(/ = |,?\s+/)
    .reduce(
      function(c, v, i, a){
        return i & 3 == 3 && (c[i >> 2] = {
          PercentageValue: a[i - 2], 
          CaseID: v
        }), c
      }, []
    )
)
```